# Connect external 4-bay SAS enclosure to HP SAS Expander Card?

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, sas

I've got an HP DL380 G7 with the [HP SAS Expander Card](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04111623.pdf). The server has 16 internal drive bays, which are all populated. It also has an external SAS connector on the expander card.

I have an external 4-bay SAS rackmount enclosure that I'm looking to connect, so I can add 4 more drives (in another RAID).  The [documentation on the expander card](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04111623.pdf) indicates that it supports:

> - 24 internal drive bays plus external port for tape

Does this mean I can't connect 4 drivers to the external port?

The canonical user documentation on the card (at [HardForum](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1484614)) indicates:

> **Q:** How do I connect harddisks to the HP SAS Expander?
>   **A:** There are 9 ports total which can connect four harddisks each. The external SFF-8088 port is Port #1.

Which implies that you *can* connect drives to the external port. In fact, the word "tape" never shows up on the first page of the forum.

Can anyone confirm?

---

**Update:** I tried it, and it did not work.